# ActionListener java swing

Tags: java, swing

i have being trying to create a window using swing ad i have to put the buttons on the right side that's why i used boxlayout but i can't find a way to use ActionListener on the button that i have. that's the program i am working on:

```
public class Fenetre2 extends JFrame {

private JSplitPane splitPan=null;

    public Fenetre2 (){
        JPanel pan = new JPanel ();

        // CARACTERISTIQUE FENETRE 
        this.setTitle("Gestion Employe");
        this.setSize(800, 400);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pan.setBackground(Color.white);
        this.setContentPane(pan);
        // ADD BUTTON  
        Container c = getContentPane();
        c.setLayout( new BorderLayout( 30, 30 ) );
        Box boxes[] = new Box[ 4 ];
        boxes[ 0 ] = Box.createHorizontalBox();
        boxes[ 1 ] = Box.createVerticalBox();
        boxes[ 2 ] = Box.createHorizontalBox();
        boxes[ 3 ] = Box.createVerticalBox();
        // create strut and add buttons to boxes[ 1 ]
        boxes[ 1 ].add( new JButton( "ajouter" ) );
        boxes[ 1 ].add( new JButton( "suprimer" ) );
        boxes[ 1 ].add( new JButton( "afficher" ) );
        c.add( boxes[ 1 ], BorderLayout.EAST );
        //TREE
        DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("STRUCTURE EMPLOYE");
        //create the child nodes
        DefaultMutableTreeNode PDGNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("PDG");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode departement1Node = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("departement 1");
        departement1Node.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("CHEF DEPARTEMENT"));
        departement1Node.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("EMPLOYEE1"));
        departement1Node.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("EMPLOYEE2"));
        departement1Node.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("EMPLOYEE3"));


        //add the child nodes to the root node
        root.add(PDGNode);
        PDGNode.add(departement1Node);
        JTree tree = new JTree(root);
        this.add(tree);
        JScrollPane scroll=new JScrollPane(tree);
        splitPan=new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT,scroll,new JLabel("aaaaa"));
        splitPan.setSize(this.getMaximumSize());
        add(splitPan);

        this.setVisible(true);          
    }
    public static void main (String args []){

        Fenetre2 fen = new Fenetre2();
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you to read this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html about how to use buttons.

Comment: If you are using java 8 you can use lambdas: `button.addActionListener(action -> {/*your code*/});`

Answer (score 1):

You should not add the buttons directly into the panel but instead instantiate them and then add an `ActionListener` to them or whatever else you want to do with them. Example:

```
JButton ajouterButton = new JButton("ajouter");
ajouterButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        // code goes here
    }
});
```

Then you can add the button to your array:

```
boxes[1].add(ajouterButton);
```

Then do the same thing to all your buttons.

Answer (score 0):

The button instance you are looking for is stored in boxes[1], so you can simply do `boxes[1].addActionListener(...);`.